# JS Fastest way to move objects inside of an array, to the body of parent object indexed by the property name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which contains an array of other objects. My goal is to move the objects from the `pets` array to the body of the `person` object. I know this can be easily done using `Object.assign`. I could iterate and do this by hand, but I'm looking for a comfortable way (ES2020 \ TS) to achieve the same goal but instead of placing the objects in a default numeric key, to place the object in a key based on the `name` property? If a property already exists then add "_1" to the key?

current code:

```
    let person = { name: "jon", pets: [{name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_red"},
                                       {name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_black"},
                                       {name: "sandor", type: "hound"},
                                       {name: "bran", type: "raven"}]};
    
    
    Object.assign(person, person.pets);
    
0: {name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_red"}
1: {name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_black"}
2: {name: "sandor", type: "hound"}
3: {name: "bran", type: "raven"}
name: "jon"
pets: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Wanted results:

```
daenerys : {name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_red"}
daenerys_1 : {name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_black"}
sandor: {name: "sandor", type: "hound"}
bran: {name: "bran", type: "raven"}
name: "jon"
pets: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write your own loop.

Answer (score 1):

when your `name` is repeated more than once

```
let person = {
    name: "jon",
    pets: [
        { name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_red" },
        { name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_black" },
        { name: "daenerys ", type: "dragon_white" },
        { name: "sandor", type: "hound" },
        { name: "bran", type: "raven" }
    ]
};

const fn = (obj) => {
    const arr = {};
    obj.pets.map((item) => {
        let index = 0;
        let name = item.name;
        while (arr[name]) {
            index++;
            name = index === 0 ? item.name : item.name + `_${index}`
        }
        arr[name] = item;
    })
    return { ...arr, ...obj };
}

console.log(fn(person));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let person = { 
  name: "jon",
  pets: 
  [
    {name: "daenerys", type: "dragon_red"},
    {name: "daenerys", type: "dragon_black"},
    {name: "sandor", type: "hound"},
    {name: "bran", type: "raven"}
   ]
};
                                       
                                       
person.pets.forEach(element =>{
  if(person[element.name] ==null){
      person[element.name] = element;
  }
  else{
   person[element.name +"_1"] = element;
  }
});
console.log(person);
```